# Per-node memory overhead

Tags: linked-list, stack

I was learning about the pros and cons of using Stacks with linked lists, when i found a cons that say: " the memory cost for each node can be significantly more than the databin stored. Ex a 32 bit value such as integer can be memory overhead 7 times larger than the integer itself."

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a general memory allocator you don't know how big block it allocates on each request. Many of them round the requested size up to some even quantity so that each block is aligned to an address divisible, say, by 8 or 16, or even 32. In that case you *always* use at least 32 bytes, even if you request only 1 byte. Then you get 32 bytes of a heap for a 4-byte piece of data, which is 8 times what you really need, thus the overhead equal 7.

**EDIT**

Often the allocator adds a 'header' before the block it returns and the header size is an allocation size step. For a header 16 bytes long your requested allocation size will get rounded up to a nearest 16 multiply and incremented by 16 for a header. So for requested size 1 through 16 you use 32 bytes, for 17—32 you use 48, for 33—48 it's 64 and so on.